# navigating to another scene using javascript in flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I have written the below code to click a skip button and to goto a certain frame in Flash cc. Now I want to use the skip button to navigate to another html file. How can I do that?

```
/*JavaScript*/
this.skipBtn.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame()
{
    this.gotoAndPlay(5);//to go to a particular frame
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.skipBtn.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoTonextPage);

function fl_ClickToGoTonextPage() {
    window.location.href = "2.html";
}
```

It has fullfilled my requirement.